# Non-degenerate distribution

Tags: statistics

What is a Non-degenerate distribution?

My understanding is that it is a distribution that changes with change of variable (non-constant distribution). Am I correct?

Comment: Have you tried Googling?

Comment: I did, but the definitions I found were not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember, it is not what you describe. At least in the univariate case, it is a probability distribution that only takes on a single value. That means that only one event has nonzero probability mass, and that is also all of the probability mass. One way to think about it would be that the distribution describes a certain event. The probability of that one event happening is 1, and no other events will occur with positive probability. However, I would recommend googling this as I am no expert and I am sure there are good sources easily available.

Comment: You have described _degenerate_ distributions, not _non-degenerate_ ones.  Otherwise, you are right.

Comment: @kimchilover oh, that's right! I guess I was a little too quick to read/answer. Thanks for clearing that up